# What does Windows 10 (updates) do if you permanently deny it network access?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

If, after installing a fresh copy of Windows 10 and applying current updates, you take the machine offline *permanently*, what will it do?

Will it work for six months then lock you out until you plug in the network cable for an update check? Or will it just run forever at the current version and not check for or nag about updates ever again?

Has anyone tried this?

(This question is not about the reasons for doing this, or the merits and demerits of the update system, just a question about the behavior.)

Comment: I'm unsure if it's relevant, but what build of Windows are you asking about?

Comment: Currently running 7 for an offline environment, which is approaching EOL. Concerned about the future, when new versions of software that I actually care about stops running on 7. So no specific version.

Comment: "Or will it just run forever" I don't think anyone has tried it yet....

Comment: Good point...probably on account of there still being a lot of forever still left.

Comment: Nothing will run forever, but without any internet access it will go for a good long time. But not really be good for anything either, as not much today does not require Internet

Answer (score 2):

> If, after installing a fresh copy of Windows 10 and applying current updates, you take the machine offline permanently, what will it do?

Windows (any version) if offline will run indefinitely.

> Will it works for six months then lock you out until you plug in the network cable for an update check?

No; Windows will never cease to function unless you are using a build that actually expires.  Only Windows Insider Preview builds expire.  If connected to the internet once a Windows 10 version is no longer supported, you will be prompted to install the next version, this request can be avoided by remaining offline.

> Will it just runs forever at the current version and not check for or nag about updates ever again?

Without knowing which version of Windows 10 you are talking about this is difficult to answer.  If we are talking about an LTSC build it will run indefinitely.  The only problem you will run into for Windows 10 Home and/or Windows 10 Professional is the inability to patch it after the support period has expired.  This is due to the fact the patches that exist on the Windows Update Catalog for those versions are only applicable to the LTSC edition.

I have personal experience attempting to update a 1507 VM, that would fail to update to a newer feature release, I was unable to use solutions like WSUS Offline due to the fact the updates no longer exist on the Windows Update Catalog.

> Has anyone tried this?

I have an entirely offline network of VMs, that have been running offline, for the better part of 5 years.  The VMs are composed of several different versions, every single VM is functional, and **works exactly like the day it was installed.**

Answer (score 0):

Here and there I have come by several VMs that run versions of windows without updates. So far nothing happens. The only thing I noticed is that certain software installations require a certain version of Windows in order to be installed or to work properly.

And yes, it will stop nagging about new updates (although it will try to check once you connect to a network)...

And in previous Windows versions, the automatic update functionality stopped working, so manual updates had to be done before the automatic updates would work again.

Disclaimer: I would not recommend running windows without security updates unless you know exactly what you are doing

Comment: Security updates only protect against network based attacks, so without a network connection, the system cannot be compromised (without a spy repelling down from the ceiling to gain physical access to the machine).

Comment: @Nick that is only partly true. First, network connectivity is not necessarily needed to infect a system (malware hidden in USB devices is only one example), secondly, malware is not the only security issue updates defend against.